# Rails email double escaping single quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a mailer in rails for a number of different emails, one of which is sent to notify users that another user has commented on something.

When the email is generated, it includes the content of the comment, so I need to ensure that the comment is escaped, which rails is doing for me by default just like in all views. This is great, but when it comes to a single quote such as apostrophe's in words, it seems to be getting double escaped. The email I receive, shows

```
„ It&#x27;s all about the quotes isn&#x27;t it. “
```

And if I inspect the HTML of the email in the rails log, it shows that the HTML produced is

```
„ It&amp;#x27;s all about the quotes isn&amp;#x27;t it. “
```

So it's being escaped correctly, but then something is escaping it a second time.
My view is an `html.haml` file.

I've tried outputting the content with the `raw` command but it didn't make a difference so I'm pretty confused as to what's going on. I know in rails 3.2.8 they changed the escaping of single quotes, so I am expecting to see the ' but not the & as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a change one of the other developers had made. They'd added sanitisation to the input so it was being escaped before being stored, and then rails was escaping it when displaying so it was being double escaped. Sorted now :)